# search of "Related To" on Activities default to a Custom Object in LEX

Tags: visualforce, activities, default-value

I am trying to set the RelatedTo field of activity to search in a custom object. In classic we can simply use URL hacking & custom button. But in lightning this solution is not viable. I tried few ideas to set default value but to no avail. By default Related To has Accounts...Also I know there is an Idea Pending with salesforce.

[image]

So if anyone know ANY way to set "Related TO" field on Activity please let me know. Is visualforce page/ lightning component to replicate the whole Activity section ..the only option?

Thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an action. Actions allow you to set the default value of fields on the layout.

https://support.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=predefined_field_values.htm

> Click the name of an action in the Buttons, Links, and Actions list or
>   the Global Actions list. On the action detail page, click New in the
>   Predefined Field Values list. Select the field you want to predefine a
>   value for. Specify the value for the field. For single-select
>   picklists, you can specify both a specific value and a formula value.
>   If you set both, the formula value takes precedence over the specific
>   value. Click Save.

Comment: The field itself can also be removed from the layout, with or without a defaulted value.

Comment: Correct, I think I had a bit of macro on the mind because macros do require the fields on the layout.

Comment: Thanks for your comment....I am aware about the action...but in this situation that won't work. Reason being using Action we can set value of any field to some value....i.e. Field A = 'xyz'.  But we don't want to set value of field "Related To" itself. We just want it to search in Another objects by default .....& not search in Account always. Please see image from question.

Comment: Also i don't want to remove it from layout.....hows that going to solve the problem

Comment: Please edit your question to be clearer about your objective, @Dnyaneshwar. Right now, you're *explicitly* asking how to set the field, not how to change the default lookup search behavior.

Comment: apologies for confusion....

Comment: Whats the use case? Why do you want to create a task for a record other than the one you are looking at? Why do you want that record to be a different object altogether? I don't think this is possible and I can't think of a good reason to justify it. If you provide a use case I might be able to provide you a better idea then quick actions. This may be an x-y problem